# Error with mysql_query in php - Can't insert information into database

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote this query in php:

```
$query = "insert into admin values($user,$pass,$email,$signature)";
mysql_query($query);
```

But it has problems and can't insert information in database. Why?
The database doesn't have any mistakes.

Comment: What "problems" does it have.  What are the results of `mysql_error()`?

Comment: how can i understand what is error? i know data doesn't enter into database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to put string within quotes.
Try in this way and check error messages.

```
$query = "insert into admin values('$user','$pass','$email','$signiture')";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: make sure not to forget to escape the strings...otherwise you could run into more errors later.  see my answer for how to do it.

Comment: @stevevls: you're right. I supposed he had already did it before passing variables to query execution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote string values:

```
$query = "insert into admin values('$user','$pass','$email','$signiture')";
```

Also your values count must match your columns count EXACTLY or else you have to explicitly list your columns out:

```
$query = "insert into admin (`username`, `password`, `email`, `signiture`)  values('$user','$pass','$email','$signiture')";
```

Also "signiture" is mis-spelt.

Answer (score 1):

For one, you need to put single quotes around your variables.  In addition, you need to make sure that your variables are [properly escaped](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) because your query will still fail if one of your variables has a single quote.

```
$query = sprintf("insert into admin values('%s','%s','%s','%s')",
        mysql_real_escape_string($user),
        mysql_real_escape_string($pass),
        mysql_real_escape_string($email),
        mysql_real_escape_string($signiture));

mysql_query($query);
```

Finally, as other users have noted, it's generally a good idea to explicitly list the columns that you wish to insert.

Answer (score 0):

you need to surround your values with single quote like this

`$query = "insert into admin values('$user','$pass','$email','$signiture')";`

If above does not work try to use the following syntax instead:

`INSERT INTO TABLE(col1,col2,col3) VALUES('val1','val2','val3')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this (may not make a difference, but worth a shot):

```
$query = "insert into admin (userColumnName, passColumnName, emailColumnName, sigColumnName) values ($user, $pass, $email, $signature)";
mysql_query($query);
```

You'll have to replace `userColumnName`, etc with the actual column names in your DB.